# Oracle Apex Custom User Accounts

Tags: oracle-apex

So I am brand new to Oracle Apex. I am wondering how I can make it so my app does not require any authorization to view the app, but you need to have an account to do certain things. Is there a way that I can authenticate these users based on whether or not they have an "account" in my database? I have a form set up as a "create account" method which inserts account data into my database. How can I go about using this database to let users "sign in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community.

Each page has the ability to be marked as 'Public', as opposed to 'Page requires authentication'

It's probably worth reading up on the authentication options - they can be based on APEX users, DB accounts, or a number of other authentication methods.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmdb/configuring-security-attributes.html#GUID-FDB41857-C144-4AB0-A85C-A33A26259A47

You can then use 'Authorisation' to determine what authenticated users can specifically do.

Try installing one of the sample applications, engage with it, then have a look to see how certain things are accomplished.

This post from Doug is also a great summary of options
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to